# React JS Mysql dependent dropdown implementation Displaying entire table on second dropdown

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, dropdown

I'm implementing dependent dropdown on react js and Mysql . On the first dropdown it should display the states and on second dropdown it should display the districts according to the state i choose.

On the first dropdown its displaying the states properly. **The issue i'm facing is on the second dropdown its displaying the districts on of both state**s. [output im getting][1]

It should not display the 4 districts it should display only top two corresponding to the first state.
Here is my react code i'm using

```
`import React, { Component } from "react";

  class DropDown extends React.Component{

state={

    users:[]
}

componentDidMount()
{
     fetch('http://localhost:5001/state')
     .then(response=>response.json())
     .then(users=>this.setState({users:users}))
}

render()
{
    return<div>
      <p1> Select State:</p1>
        <select>
        <option>-select state-</option>
            {
               
                this.state.users.map(users=><option value="users.value">{users.state_name}</option>)
               
            }
        </select><br></br>
    
    </div>
    }
    }
    export  default DropDown;`
```

[Mysql Table for States][2]
I'm getting the desired output for this code.

For districts Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class DistDropdown extends React.Component
```

{

```
state={
    user:[]
}

componentDidMount()
{

     fetch('http://localhost:5001/district')
     .then(response=>response.json())
     .then(user=>this.setState({user:user}))
}


render()
{
    return<div>
    
        
        <p1>Select District</p1>
        <select onClick={this.data}>
            <option>-select district-</option>
            {
             this.state.user.map(user=><option value="user.value">{user.district_name}</option>)
            }
        </select> 
    </div>
}
```

}
export  default DistDropdown;

Here i'm facing the issue i mentioned For Tamilnadu it only should display "Salem and Ooty". Here its displaying the districts for the second state also.
[My sql table for Districts][3]

The code i'm using for server is by node js.

```
app.get('/state',function(req,res)
{
var sql="SELECT *FROM state_table.new_table";
con.query(sql,function(err,users)
{
 if (err)throw error;
  res.send(JSON.stringify(users));
  console.log(users);
 });
 });

 app.get('/district',function(req,res)
 {
 var sql="SELECT *FROM state_table.district_name";
 con.query(sql,function(err,user)
 {
 if (err)throw error;

 res.send(JSON.stringify(user));
 console.log(user);

 });
```

Is there a possible way to change the code as my requirement. I'm stuck with this issue for long , any helps regarding this issue be very much helpful for me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvJyv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibhZP.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/exYH7.png